# Bottom Sheet Animation, Mini Music player to full screen Music player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, bottom-sheet, android-music-player

I am struggling to add media functionality to the app. At this point I am stuck to have a professional visual transition for mini player to full screen media player.

While It is a common feature for music player app, I could not find any article or guide related to this.

I am using Bottom sheet to handle mini player. Basically , my question is how to handle the transition of bottom sheet state from STATE COLLAPSED to STATE EXPANDED like in the video.

```
Desired Result:
```

[image: Video depict]

Thanks for reading this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you read `shared element transition` (ex : https://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition) ?

Comment: In my opinion, you can build that bottom sheet with a cardview, an do shared element transition to get animation.

Comment: Thank you for the opinion. As far as I know shared element transitions are for acitvity or fragment transition. And I think they don't use a separate activity or fragment to create their full screen media player. To make up for my lack of information I am gong to read about shared element transition for bottom sheet dialog fragment :)

Comment: You're welcome, if you think they do not, but I think they use two different activity/fragment to do that. Because it's more clean in code if you separate them between library activity/fragment and fullscreen activity/fragment. But its just in my opinion :)

Comment: How you achieved this ?>

Comment: Not totally. For now I implemented a new activity as the @MrX suggested. The system works fine. But for this behaviour https://medium.com/vrt-digital-studio/picture-in-picture-video-overlay-with-motionlayout-a9404663b9e7 this link can help. If you can achieve please share the results :)

Comment: https://medium.com/@Bytepace/animation-like-in-youtube-application-b811785ad31d  this one is more detailed